# WKWebView not scrollable at first

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView in my iOS application.

I create it like this (because doing it via storyboard creates a build time error)

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
view.insertSubview(webView, at: 0)
```

now the thing is that when I want to scroll the page after it's loaded I have to make the gesture twice -- on the first scroll it does not react at all.

I tried calling webView.becomeFirstResponder() after web is loaded but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: webConfiguration)
```

Comment: unfortunately still the same

Comment: Mmm the view is inside scrollView or tableView? You can try scroll automatic when is loaded (It's no the best, but this is weird) `webView.scrollView.scrollToTop()` Maybe help you.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it should work

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

Also, check Documentation for WKWebView inside Xcode.

Comment: basically the same code as mine --  "Also, check Documentation for WKWebView inside Xcode." what kind of advice is that?

Comment: First of all, You said your problem is that you have to make gesture twice, with mine you don't have to make GESTURE TWICE. It works on the first time.
Secondly, Check Documentation means: Inside Xcode, there is documentation for WKWebView, with examples on how to use WKWebView.
Thirdly, Don't comment without trying out the suggestions.
Remove the -1 and Accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: your suggestion does not work and i've read the documentation. General  suggestion "Read the documentation" without any further hints is not helpful at all. Your answer is rubbish, hence -1, if you don't like it remove your answer

Comment: It is surely working on mine, maybe you have some other issue then.